# storyboard access element in a control template

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a usercontrol that contains a custom styled button that I wish to animate.

```
<UserControl>
<!-- omitted namespaces etc -->
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Style x:Key="myButtonStyle">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                   <Grid>                                                                     
                     <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="Orange" />
                     <es:Arc x:Name="arc" EndAngle="360" Fill="Red" StartAngle="360"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
           </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
  </Style>
</UserControl.Resouces>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" />
  <Button Tap="Fire_Animation" x:Name="myButton" Style="{StaticResource myButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Once the Button is Tapped, the Fire_Animation method starts a storyboard which is supposed to modify the "Arc" element inside the button's template.

I've seen examples for WPF like this:

```
// .. previous necessary method calls
StoryBoard.SetTargetName(_myAnimation, "arc");
_storyboard.Begin(myButton, myButton.Template);
```

But there's no such 'Begin' overload in Windows Phone and as such my storyboard raises an exception that it can't find the 'arc' element. Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that when you tap the button, that it sets a visual state. You can then provide a storyboard as part of your button template that animates the `arc` element when the given visual state is applied.